# Edited aug 24 9pm - number game isn't working as I would like

Tags: python

I have a number guessing game working but I would like it to count without pick numbers without having them have any with a single increment. What I am trying to say is 2 4 17 27 not 2 3 4 17 27 I would like it to go through all the possibilities from low to high like it is, just not with any in a single increment IE 1 2 3 or 5 6.

I would also like it to be able to do from 1 to 100 and the count length to go to 10. If I try and put anymore than 6 in it will not work.

```
It gives me a result like this now
Please enter the lower limit: 2
Please enter the upper limit: 9
Please enter the number of values in sequences: 6

Possible sequences. Spot the missing one!

    [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]    #I do not want it to have them all 1 digit up at a time
    [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8]    #like this
    [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 9]
    [2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8]
    [2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 9]
    [2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9]
    [2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8]
    [2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 9]
    [2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 9]
    [2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9]
    [2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8]
    [2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 9]
    [2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9]
    [2, 3, 5, 7, 8, 9]
    [2, 3, 6, 7, 8, 9]



    Please enter the lower limit: 2
    Please enter the upper limit: 13
    Please enter the number of values in sequences: 6

    [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]    #I would like it more like this
    [2, 4, 7, 9, 11]    #so it go's through low to high but with out 1 digit 
    [2, 5, 7, 9, 11]    #increments
    [2, 5, 9, 11, 13]   
    [2, 6, 9, 11, 13]
    [2, 7, 9, 11, 13,]
```

If anyone has any suggestions please let me know.

```
import itertools
import random

DEBUG = False
ALLOWED_GUESSES = 3


def get_game_parameters():
    while True:
        try:
            lower_limit = int(input("Please enter the lower limit: "))
            upper_limit = int(input("Please enter the upper limit: "))
            consecutive_length = int(input("Enter The Number Limit For Consecutive Increments: "))
            if lower_limit > upper_limit:
                raise ValueError("Lower limit must not exceed upper limit")

            sequence_length = int(input("Please enter the number of values in sequences: "))

            if upper_limit - lower_limit < sequence_length:
                raise ValueError("Difference in limits must be greater than sequence length")

        except ValueError as  e:
            print("Invalid value entered:", e)
            continue
        else:
            sequence_range = range(lower_limit, upper_limit + 2)
            return sequence_range, sequence_length

###input ("Enter The Number Limit For Consecutive Increments: ")

def prompt_user_to_guess(chosen_sequence, required_sequence_length):
    guesses_made = 0
    while True:
        try:
            user_input = input(
                "Please enter your guess for the hidden sequence, " +\
                "separating terms by commas (e.g. '1, 2, 3, 4'): ")

            guessed_sequence = [int(x) for x in user_input.split(",")]
            if len(guessed_sequence) != required_sequence_length:
                raise ValueError("Incorrect number of arguments")
        except ValueError as e:
            print("Invalid guess:", e)
            continue
        else:
            guesses_made += 1

            if guessed_sequence == chosen_sequence:
                print("You guessed the correct sequence. Well done!")
                return
            elif guesses_made < ALLOWED_GUESSES:
                remaining_guesses = ALLOWED_GUESSES - guesses_made
                print("Incorrect guess! {} attempt(s) remaining.".format(remaining_guesses))
                continue
            else:
                print("I'm sorry, you're out of guesses. The correct sequence was {}".format(chosen_sequence))
                return


def generate_possible_sequences(sequence_range, sequence_length):
    def is_monotonic_increasing(l):
        return all(x < y for x, y in zip(l, l[1:]))

    for permutation in itertools.permutations(sequence_range, sequence_length):
        if is_monotonic_increasing(permutation):
            yield list(permutation)


def main():
    sequence_range, sequence_length = get_game_parameters()

    possible_sequences = list(generate_possible_sequences(sequence_range, sequence_length))

    chosen_sequence = possible_sequences.pop(random.randrange(len(possible_sequences)))
    assert chosen_sequence not in possible_sequences

    if DEBUG:
        print("\nChosen sequence: {}".format(chosen_sequence))

    print("\nPossible sequences. Spot the missing one!\n")
    for sequence in possible_sequences:
        print(sequence)

    prompt_user_to_guess(chosen_sequence, sequence_length)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not clear on what exactly you are answering, and we need a better explanation of "it will not work". However, it looks like you generate far too many options in `generate_possible_sequences()` which probably results in either memory filling up or far too long an execution time. A better approach is to just shuffle numbers in range, then sort a sub-sequence, like so:

```
sequence_range, sequence_length = get_game_parameters()
vals = range(1, sequence_range + 1)
random.shuffle(vals)
chosen_sequence = sorted(vals[:sequence_length])
```

This will work almost instantly for `sequence_range` values well into the thousands, and you can step through it interactively to see how the code it working. However, for millions of elements (or just shorter code overall), the `random.sample()` function does what you want in just one line and without shuffling the complete list:

```
sequence_range, sequence_length = get_game_parameters()
chosen_sequence = sorted(random.sample(xrange(1, sequence_range + 1), sequence_length))
```

The `xrange()` here avoids creating an actual list in memory; this line gives an out of memory error:

```
random.sample(range(1, 999999999), 4)
```

This line works:

```
random.sample(xrange(1, 999999999), 4)
```

You probably also want:

```
guessed_sequence.sort()
```

This allows the user to input in any order.

Comment: I tried making the changes to the code a you suggested although I'm not sure I did it correctly. I am just having is ask for the inputs then when it should run it just asks for the inputs again.